# passing table name column name and value of a column in oracle databsase

Tags: oracle, plsql

code in jsp page

```
 CallableStatement cs ;
cs=conn.prepareCall("{call held1(?,?,?)}"); 
cs.setString(1,"'"+session.getAttribute("roll")+"'"); // sending session to procedure .reciving this in s variable
cs.setString(2, "1");// sending serial nos as string and wanna recieve in sno. variable
cs.setString(3, "Monday"); // sending table name as string and wanna recieve it in tab variable
cs.executeUpdate();
```

"'"+session.getAttribute("roll")+"'" want to recive this value in s argument
"1"

code in oracle database

procedure

```
create or replace procedure "HELD1"
(s  VARCHAR2,sno  VARCHAR2,tab  VARCHAR2)
is
l_col_name varchar2(30);
begin
execute immediate
'SELECT SUBJECTCODE into l_col_name FROM '||tab||' WHERE SERIALNUMBER ='''||sno||'''';

    execute immediate 
    'UPDATE dprofile SET '|| l_col_name || ' = ' || l_col_name || ' + 1 WHERE       Rollno = ''' ||s || '''';
end;
```

- s : Value of RollNo
- sno : Serial No. Passed as argument String
- tab : Name Of Table Passed as Argument to Procedure

Error Message:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00905: missing keyword ORA-06512: at
>   "ROHIT.HELD1", line 8 ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: The way you define your problem no one able to help you better explain your problem in detail with proper information

Comment: I think the problem with `into`. Use execute immediate `<ur select statement>` into `<variables>` and then process.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT INTO`.. portion of *dynamic* SQL execution goes like below.

```
execute immediate
'SELECT SUBJECTCODE  FROM '||tab||' WHERE SERIALNUMBER ='''||sno||''''
into l_col_name;
```

The Query execution is dynamic to SQL Engine.. but still the data is brought back to the PL/SQL engine. So, the fetching part happens after SQL execution only.

You are prone to [`SQL*Injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Atleast use bind variables for the where clause.

```
execute immediate
    'SELECT SUBJECTCODE  FROM '||tab||' WHERE SERIALNUMBER = :sno'
    into l_col_name
    using sno;

execute immediate 
'UPDATE dprofile '||
   ' SET '|| l_col_name || ' = ' || l_col_name || ' + 1 '||
   ' WHERE  Rollno = :s'
using s;
```

And finally, in your jdbc portion.

```
cs.setString(1,session.getAttribute("roll"));
```

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ORA-06512: at "ROHIT.HELD1", line 13 ORA-06512: at line 1 ........................this the error now after making amendments

Comment: where does this value come into.. is that, in `SELECT` or `UPDATE` ? Perhaps, you pasted a different version of query here.

Comment: value is taken from select into 1_col_name  and then this 1_col_nam is updated

Comment: @user3738332 Do you use a alias name in the table part.. perhaps, you missed something in your actual query. What ever you shown us here for the update query is fine.

Comment: i have made two table one is dprofile and another is monday which is passed as string from jsp page and received in tab variable

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: `cs.setString(1,"'"+session.getAttribute("roll")+"'");` , donot send with sinbgle quotes.. just use  `cs.setString(1,session.getAttribute("roll"));`

Comment: @user3738332 otheriwse,what ever the column name in  `l_col_name` is not `NUMBER` ?

Answer (score 0):

> execute immediate
>   'SELECT SUBJECTCODE into l_col_name FROM '||tab||' WHERE SERIALNUMBER ='''||sno||'''';

The **INTO** clause should be after the dynamic sql.

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE <dynamic sql> INTO variable;`

Do not get confused with `SELECT .. INTO`. You are dealing with dynamic sql. First the query is executed and then the returned values are assigned to the respective variables. There is context switching involved between **PL/SQL** and **SQL** engines.